# Билинейная интерполяция таблицы python

Tags: python

Я не программист, но нужно найти коэффициент Ню при известных ro и xi. Пробовал уже много вариантов включая interp2d, ничего не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

ro = 12
xi = 9.17

Table_11_6_x = [5, 10, 20 ,40 , 80, 160, 350]
Table_11_6_y = [0.1, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160]
x,y = np.meshgrid(Table_11_6_x, Table_11_6_y)

st1 = [0.95, 0.92, 0.88, 0.83, 0.76, 0.67, 0.56]
st2 = [0.89, 0.87, 0.84, 0.8, 0.73, 0.65, 0.54]
st3 = [0.85, 0.84, 0.81, 0.77, 0.71, 0.64, 0.53]
st4 = [0.8, 0.78, 0.76, 0.73, 0.68, 0.61, 0.51]
st5 = [0.72, 0.72, 0.7, 0.67, 0.63, 0.57, 0.48]
st6 = [0.63, 0.63, 0.61, 0.59, 0.56, 0.51, 0.44]
st7 = [0.53, 0.53, 0.52, 0.5, 0.47, 0.44, 0.38]

Table_11_6 = np. array([st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7])

f = interpolate.interpn((x, y), Table_11_6, (ro, xi), method = 'splinef2d')
Table_11_6
```

Comment: мне кажется вместо (x, y) нужно (Table_11_6_x, Table_11_6_y)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Все работает!

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

ro = 12
xi = 9.17

Table_11_6_x = [5, 10, 20 ,40 , 80, 160, 350]
Table_11_6_y = [0.1, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160]

st1 = [0.95, 0.92, 0.88, 0.83, 0.76, 0.67, 0.56]
st2 = [0.89, 0.87, 0.84, 0.8, 0.73, 0.65, 0.54]
st3 = [0.85, 0.84, 0.81, 0.77, 0.71, 0.64, 0.53]
st4 = [0.8, 0.78, 0.76, 0.73, 0.68, 0.61, 0.51]
st5 = [0.72, 0.72, 0.7, 0.67, 0.63, 0.57, 0.48]
st6 = [0.63, 0.63, 0.61, 0.59, 0.56, 0.51, 0.44]
st7 = [0.53, 0.53, 0.52, 0.5, 0.47, 0.44, 0.38]

Table_11_6 = np. array([st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7])

f = interpolate.interpn((Table_11_6_x, Table_11_6_y), Table_11_6, (ro, xi), method = 'splinef2d')
```

Comment: Хоть напишите, в чем была проблема, и "вот правильный ответ"

Comment: Конечно, извините. По совету я напрямую поставил значения Table_11_6_x и Table_11_6_y в функцию интерполяции.

Comment: по-моему тут x и y перепутаны в предыдущем ответе